# Lab Order Messaeg OML_O21, Which Response Message should we get from Lab?

Tags: hl7

We need help regarding Laboratory related events,
We are right now using OML_O21 Message to send Laboratory Order from HIS.
Then here we get an acknowledgment Message as ORL_O22. Till here we have understood.

But When we are expecting the results from Laboratory after successful completion of test, Which Message-Event we should use?
Is it possible to use same OML_O21 as response from Lab? Because in OML_O21 itself we are already having the OBX segment which is used to send Result in OML_O21.

Can anyone have solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use either OUL^R21 (Unsolicited laboratory observation), OUL^R22 (specimen oriented observation), OUL^R24 (order oriented) or OUL^R23 (specimen container oriented).

Comment: Hey thank you, i was a little confused that cant we use same OML_O21 for the response as well? If you have any idea then please share.

Answer (score 1):

OML is for orders (chapter 4 of HL7), OUL and ORU are for results (chapter 7 of HL7). Download the HL7 v2.5 specs for free from hl7.org